# Querying through polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Just playing around RoR, trying to find a way through some modelling.
Please, mind the code below:

```
 class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
 end

 class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
 end

 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
 end
```

*Is there a way to get a Product by its specific Picture?*
I'm trying this, but its not working:

```
picure = Picture.last
product = Product.where(picture: picure)
```

Its failing with:

````
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: products.picture: SELECT "products".*
FROM "products" WHERE "products"."picture" IS NULL LIMIT 1```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an instance of `Picture` `@picture`, you can use the `belongs_to` to get it's associated `Product` (assuming it the `Picture` is in fact belonging to an instance of `Product` and not `Employee`)

```
product = @picture.imageable
```

Comment: I don't have an `product` instance. All I need is get to one, but from a `picture` instance, actually. Thank you for answering.

Comment: That's what my answer is showing you how to do; given a `Picture` instance `@picture`, the `imageable` association on `@picture` will return it's associated `Product` instance.

Comment: Oh, I see.. But what `belongs_to` you're referring to? The polymorphic one or a new one? (I'll need to get `Employees` by this, also).

Comment: You only have one `belongs_to` defined in your `Picture` model. The way you have set things up, a single `Picture` instance can only be associated with either an `Employee` **or** a `Product`, not both.

Comment: Wait, but isn't that what Polymorphic Associations are only about? `Empolyees` and `Products`, both, having associations with the picture model?
LOL! Maybe I'm going totally wrong on this. I'm trying to get started, very newb. :)

Comment: A polymorphic association lets you have a single model (`Picture`) contain an association (`belongs_to :imageable`) which points to an arbitrary model (`Employee` or `Product`). This effectively allows for the `Picture` model to be reused (many models in a website might need to have a picture associated with it, whether it be a user's profile, a product, etc...). Without the polymorphism, you'd otherwise be left duplicating code and effort by having both an `EmployeePicture` model and a `ProductPicture` model.

Comment: A polymorphic association does **not** mean a single instance of the model containing the polymorphic association can simultaneously reference **multiple** models through it's single polymorphic `belongs_to`.

Comment: Well, ok. So assuming our `Picture.last` has an exclusive association to one of our products, and to no other (products or employees)... yet taking that it is doing it by our `imageable` polymorphic association. How could be possible get to that `product` by querying our `picture`?
Just ```@picture.imageable```?

Comment: I'm not sure how many more times you need me to point you back to my original answer; **use the `imageable` association on the `Picture` instance**

Comment: Oh my, I just noticed I'm taking Picture instance by Picture model since your second reply. Sorry, very. Thanks for answering. :)